# Why can't I sort a date array returned by my firebase query?

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, sorting

I have a sort function that works on a hard coded date array. But when I try to sort on a date array created by my firebase query, I am unable to sort.

```
//THIS DOES NOT SORT
const dayRef = firebase.database().ref('Calendar/District/' + district + '/validDays/');
dayRef.once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
    var value = snapshot.val();
    if (value) {
        snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
            var myDate = childSnapshot.val();
            days.push(new Date(myDate.date)); //ARRAY DOES NOT SORT
        });
    }
});

// THIS SORTS MY HARD CODED ARRAY
var dates = [
    new Date(2010, 5, 10),
    new Date(2010, 2, 10),
    new Date(2010, 3, 10),
    new Date(2010, 8, 10),
    new Date(2010, 1, 10),
    new Date(2010, 6, 10),
    new Date(2010, 11, 10),
    new Date(2010, 8, 10)];

var date_sort_asc = function (date1, date2) {
    if (date1 > date2) return 1;
    if (date1 < date2) return -1;
    return 0;
};

console.log(dates.sort(date_sort_asc)) // this sorts
console.log(days.sort(date_sort_asc)) // this does not sort
</script>
```

I need to sort the days array in ascending order

Comment: Please, show us an example of `dates` array that is returned from firebase, before sorting

Comment: You should sort in your .then. Now you are trying to sort before the `then` is actually resolved... Sort after your `snapshot.forEach` since you use asynchronous code.

Comment: *"The code below is fully functional for testing."*: good reason to upvote :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort Javascript Object Array By Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date)

Answer (score 2):

You are sorting before the promise is resolved.

```js
if (value) {
    snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
        var myDate = childSnapshot.val();
        days.push(new Date(myDate.date)); //ARRAY DOES NOT SORT, yet...
    });
    days.sort(date_sort_asc); // <-- Do it here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code for firebase is asynchronous. You should sort in the .then block, after your foreach loop. Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cwefv2oa/)

```
snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
    var myDate = childSnapshot.val();
    days.push(new Date(myDate.date));
 });
 days.sort(date_sort_asc); // Sort here
 console.log(days);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Jonathon Hamel - this is the answer...
Sort after your snapshot.forEach since you use asynchronous code.